# Laravel 7: Problems with request in registration form

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-7

Hello i have a problem with the registration in laravel.

In my register.blade.php there's a table that the user fills with a js function.
When i click on submit button i need to fetch datas from that table but i don't have a key mapping the table in the $request variable

That's the part of the code where i put the table:

```
 <table class="table align-content-center" id="compList"  name="compList">
      <thead>
           <tr>
               <th scope="col">Competence</th>
               <th scope="col">Level</th>
               <th scope="col">Remove</th>
           </tr>
      </thead>
 </table>
```

Comment: you could create hidden inputs in the table, so when you submit the form the fields you need are also sent. example: <input id="prodId" name="level" type="hidden" value="my_value">

Comment: Thanks, that helped me solving my problem

Answer (score 1):

You should use form attribute to fetch data from it.
You can rewrite this part code as follows :

```
<form name="compList" class="table align-content-center" id="compList">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Competence</th>
                    <th scope="col">Level</th>
                    <th scope="col">Remove</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
    </form>
```